# Что означает знак ? в коде

Tags: c#

Пример строки из декомпилированного кода.

```cs
stringWriter?.Close();
```

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, вроде ж не дубликат?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запись `stringWriter?.Close()` идентична коду:

```cs
if (stringWriter != null) stringWriter.Close();
```

То-есть метод `Close()` вызывется только в случае, если есть, откуда его вызывать

Comment: Спс), все не мог правильно загуглить). Как гора с плечь.

Comment: @maxmirrow а в от начни вы с прочтения книг с базой для новичков - проблемы бы не было

Comment: Не совсем так. При многопоточном использовании есть нюанс.

Comment: Прочитал 2 книги по c#, 2 по phyton и ещё много про алгоритмы и многое другое. Извини что не запомнил это и не попалось мне на практике такая ситуация до этого момента. Верю что получился детский вопрос))

Comment: @Qwertiy, а можно небольшую наводку, что за нюанс такой?

Comment: @kertAW, там промежуточная переменная, которая обеспечивает однократный доступ к старой. Если при `if (stringWriter != null) stringWriter.Close();` кто-то в другом потоке сделает `stringWriter = null`, то оно может грохнуться, а при `?.` - нет. https://stackoverflow.com/q/32734119/4928642